# Homogeneous Wave Equation with None-Homogeneous Boundary Condition: using Separation of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations, self-learning, wave-equation

I looked for similar questions and I found [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1776125/homogeneous-wave-equation-with-dirichlet-conditions) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177579/homogeneous-wave-equation-on-half-line-with-nonhomogeneous-boundary-condition);

But these two questions are about another method. I want to solve the following problem with Separation of Variables. 
$$
\begin{cases}
u_{tt}=u_{xx}\\
u(x,0)=x \\
u_t(x,0)=0 \\
u_x(0,t)=2\sin(t)\\
u_x(\pi,t)=0
\end{cases}
$$

I know how to solve the Homogeneous Wave Equations with Homogeneous B.Cs,
but I have no idea for this problem.

**Reply to the comment:**

 I know I have to write $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$, but I don't know how to complete the answer:
$$
u(x,t)=X(x)T(t) \quad\Rightarrow \quad XT''=X''T
$$
$$
\Rightarrow\quad \frac{X''}{X}=\frac{T''}{T}=\lambda \quad \Rightarrow$$
\begin{cases}
X''-\lambda X=0 \\
X'(0)T(t)=2\sin(t)\\
X'(\pi)=0
\end{cases}
Now from the $X'(0)T(t)=2\sin(t)$ what we get?
$$
X'(0)T(t)=2\sin(t) \Longrightarrow T(t)\int X'(x)dx|_{x=0} = \int 2\sin(t)dx$$ $$ \Rightarrow X(x)|_{x=0}T(t)=2x\sin(t) 
$$
It looks not to be correct!  I mean, is $X(0)=0$ ?

Comment: Let $u(x,t)=F(x)G(t)$ and write the problem and constrains with these form.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If
\begin{cases}
u_x(0,t)=p\\
u_x(\pi,t)=q
\end{cases}
we at first make vanish $p$ and $q$ with another assumption. Let $u(x,t)=v(x,t)+w(x,t)$ so for $w(x,t)=\alpha x+\beta$, from
\begin{cases}
u_x(0,t)=2\sin t\\
u_x(\pi,t)=0
\end{cases}
we have $w(x,t)=(-\dfrac{2}{\pi}\sin t)x+2\sin t$ and from $u(x,0)=v(x,0)+w(x,0)$ we know $v(x,0)=x$, also with $u_t(x,0)=v_t(x,0)+w_t(x,0)$ then $v_t(x,0)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}x-2$, so new problem takes the form
\begin{cases}
v_{tt}=v_{xx}+\left(-\dfrac{2}{\pi}x+2\right)\sin t\\
v(x,0)=x \\
v_t(x,0)=\dfrac{2}{\pi}x-2 \\
v_x(0,t)=0\\
v_x(\pi,t)=0
\end{cases}

Comment: Thank you, now I can solve the problem completely :)

Comment: You need to modify the wave equation as well: $w_{tt} \neq w_{xx}$, so there's now an extra inhomogeneous term.

Comment: @Chappers Thanks. I'll correct that.

Comment: This equation is not homogeneous! For solving that, I need to change it to a homogeneous one again! Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the boundary condition is. But the PDE have $(\frac{-2}{\pi}x+2)sin(t)$, and because of that, the PDE is not homogeneous.

Comment: Like ODE we solve homogeneous form and then find special answer.